# I can connect on console but not on compass

Tags: mongodb

I have the following connect string and I can connect with it through my console but I can't seem to connect using Compass?

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://mymongodbhost.com/testdb" --username user1 --password pass1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be passing the entire connection string in the hostname field. Can you try using just the host name?